# Concerns about locks when using concurent java jdbc queries

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb

I'll appreciate your help with this one.

my project runs on a java EJB environment. 
using postgress database and running native JDBC queries.

till now, I had a singleton which was the only one that was responsible to update and insert records to the database. each process that might needed to update the db was guaranteed to be the only one to do it in a given time.

however, a new a-synchronized scheduled process had been added which responsible to delete old records from the db tables, the same tables.
the deletion is done in constant size chunks. each one in a different transaction (using RequiresNew for each transaction).

my concern is about potential locks that might occurred (when trying to delete and update the same tables/records at the same time).
what do you think? is this scenario possible?
if true, what can I do to prevent it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [postgres jdbc driver description](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/thread.html) all things will be ok. This driver is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

The database will just lock the record while deleting or updating each will waiting on the other.
long as delete does not take a long time should not be a problem